# SSIS package Error

Tags: ssis

i have updated the old SSIS Load package. i have changed the variable names and some other stuff but when i try to execute package it gives me error for old variable names that variable not found. now i checked it so many times, i have no old variable name defined anywhere then why its giving me error for previous variable names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to diagnose your issue without any error messages or detail, but you could view the xml (think it's View menu, then Code), and search the XML text for any instances of the old variable that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that you are referencing the old variable name in an expression somewhere.  If you are allowed in your environment, download [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/).  It will highlight expressions for you to make them easier to find and correct.